# How to await on next() in a middleware

Tags: node.js, express

Using express, i have a middleware like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  next();
});
```

How to wait on this next() to finish pls ?
The reason i'm asking is i added console.log after next(), this message is happening before the message in the next route function.

```
app.use(async(req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  await next();
  console.log('should be the last print but ...');
});
```

Comment: There is no interface for `next()` in Express to know when all other request handlers are done.   `next()` itself is basically asynchronous so you can't tell from when it returns when the other request handlers are done.  `next()` just kicks off the next link in the router and when it returns does not necessarily have anything to do with when the routing is done.  So, your question can't really be done that way.

Comment: Oh, and `next()` doesn't return a promise so you can't use `await` with it to learn anything about when it's done.  For a more promise-centric design, you may want to check out either [Koa](https://koajs.com/) or [Express v5 (in alpha)](https://scotch.io/tutorials/whats-new-in-expressjs-5-0#toc-proposed-changes-in-the-near-future).

Answer (score 5):

I encountered this problem in my project and we went for a quick work around where we split the middleware in two. You add the first part before the routing and the things you want to execute after the "next()" in another one which you add afterwards. If you need to access the same object instances or something you can always save it in the request locals.

My example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5050;
const wait = (milliseconds) =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res();
        }, milliseconds);
    });

const middleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('- 1');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('- 2');
    next();
    console.log('- 3');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('- 4');
    console.log('');
};
app.use(middleware);
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('-- 1');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('-- 2');
    console.log('hello');
    res.send('Hello World!');
    console.log('-- 3');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('-- 4');
    next();
    return;
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

This would have the issue you encountered. It would print something amongst those lines.

```
- 1
- 2
-- 1
- 3
-- 2
hello
-- 3
- 4

-- 4
```

The solution:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 5050;
const wait = (milliseconds) =>
    new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res();
        }, milliseconds);
    });

const middleware1 = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('- 1');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('- 2');
    next();
};

const middleware2 = async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('- 3');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('- 4');
    console.log('');
    next();
};

app.use(middleware1);
app.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('-- 1');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('-- 2');
    console.log('hello');
    res.send('Hello World!');
    console.log('-- 3');
    await wait(10);
    console.log('-- 4');
    next();
    return;
});
app.use(middleware2);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

You split the middlewares in two so as to make sure that middleware2 is executed only after everything in the route is executed. You would get an output like:

```
- 1
- 2
-- 1
-- 2
hello
-- 3
-- 4
- 3
- 4
```

Comment: I think you are right! there is no other solution, shame for Expressjs!